# Edit image in FOSUserBundle

Tags: image, edit, fosrestbundle

I need help to edit image profil.I can register in FOSUserBundle ( adding image to database, and other ) and replay a profil (replay all custom from database) and i can edit profile except  the image.I follow the tutotiel:

http://fr.openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/fosuserbundle-erreur-d-authentification-1

i need help to edit image profil and thinks.